# Is this a shift in tense?

Tags: writing-style, grammar, tenses

I'm having a problem understanding tense shifts. Take for example:

> Pittsburgh Public *managed* to hold to this tradition once again by *bringing* this ageless piece of musical theater to life with freshness as well as a salute back to the days of theater past.

Why is the sentence set up in past tense with "managed" but then uses "bringing". Wouldn't this be an inappropriate tense shift?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: EDL has given the technical details in their answer, but basically this is how language works. You wouldn't say "by brought this...", would you? It's very uncommon to have a tense mistake within a single sentence (certainly for native speakers). When I think of tense problems, I think of something like this: "John threw the ball. The dog runs and fetches it. John patted the dog."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of your sentence is **Pittsburg Public** and the verb is **managed**.

This makes, in a sense, the rest of the sentence a kind of object.  The **this tradition** is the direct object, since you could end the sentence right here.  The word **bringing** is a gerund:

> [ger·und](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20gerund&oq=define%20gerund&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.3670j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
>
> /ˈjerənd/
>
> a form that is derived from a verb but that functions as a noun, in English ending in -ing, e.g., do you mind my asking you?.

making the rest of the phrase an [indirect gerund phrase](https://englishsentences.com/gerund-phrase/). It's indirect because it can't stand on its own as a separate sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just change "Pittsburgh Public managed" to read "Pittsburgh Public has managed" and call it a day. Seems to mitigate the tenses.